# Wordpress query_posts(...) by page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

With wordpress I am trying to figure out how to get the current page number and use it with the `query_posts` function i have tried passing in `page=1` but that doesnt seem to work

```
query_posts( "cat=4&posts_per_page=1" ); // how do i pass in the page number???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
query_posts( array( 'cat' => 8, 'posts_per_page' => 25, 'paged' => get_query_var('page') ) );
```

Comment: sorry, not sure what happened there